# Non activity class notification not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a notification appear in the notification manager from a non activity class, but I can't make it happen

```
public void showNotification(Context context) {
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif1)
                .setContentTitle("Car crash occure!")
                .setContentText("Tap to view location.");

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class), 0);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: you missed to add an icon , seems like same issue i answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442075/notification-is-not-displayed-using-notificationcompat-builder/41442588#41442588

Answer (score -2):

Use Intent Service instead of Activity

```
public static class NotificationActionService extends IntentService {
    public NotificationActionService() {
        super(NotificationActionService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_1.equals(action)) {

            Log.d("ACTION_NOTIFICATION", "Notification Clicked");
        }
        // TODO: handle action 1.
        // If you want to cancel the notification: NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: The pending intent for a Notification can be a Service or Activity.  This won't fix anything.  If anything an Activity is more frequently used.